# Program shall utilize full processor but full utilization of CPU is not good

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, coding-style, cpu-usage

I attended a programmers' meet today:

One guy said:

> A good program utilizes maximum processor

And according to general computing:

> When task manager shows **100% utilization**. It means your PC need some medications.

A program when using maximum processor will push task manager to 100%.

These 2 things are sounding so conflicting. Can someone please clarify with justifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows how silly ideas flow around the programmer community.

All the CPU utilization tells you is, very roughly, what fraction of time the program spends computing versus waiting, possibly for I/O, possibly for unrelated processing. Also, if you have a 4-core machine, 25% could mean 100% of one core.

Some programs *should* be I/O bound because their primary job is to read/write files or other I/O. Their CPU utilization should be low.
Others should be CPU-bound.
But that doesn't tell you if either one is "efficient".

A program is efficient when it does nothing *unnecessary*.
You can easily make a program appear CPU-bound or I/O-bound just by making it do everything twice!
If you see a high CPU percent, or high I/O utilization, when as far as you're concerned the computer should be idle, it means something is running, and you should be suspicious that it is not something you want.

I only know one way to make programs efficient, and that is by *diagnosing* what they are doing, and eliminating anything that takes time and can be removed.
[*Example.*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/302345/2429)

Comment: Why shall we not write programs which save processing power? Not sure if this is a good question, because **saving** things in general is considered good.

Comment: @student: A program is either computing, or waiting, so it is using either 100% of its core, or 0%. If you see it using some other percent, like 40%, that is a time-average over a second, more or less. A perfectly optimal program may use 100% CPU, or almost none. I don't know what you mean by *saving* things, but percent CPU is not something you should pay much attention to. What you should do is learn how to *diagnose* what is costing time - wall clock time.